# Trying to work out time difference without date method

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java, so please forgive me.

I am trying to create a time report using java. I am trying to not use the date method.

I wrote a code asking a user to enter his hours and min for his entry and exit time.

Here's my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setting the initial time for work
        int beginningHours = 0;
        int exitHours = 0;
        int beginningMin = 0;
        int exitMin = 0;

        //we are creating an entry system
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("please enter your entry hours. [0-23]");
            beginningHours = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter your entry minutes. [0-59]");
            beginningMin = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("please enter your exit hours. [0-23]");
            exitHours = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("please enter your exit minutes. [0-59]");
            exitMin = keyboard.nextInt();
        } while (beginningHours > 25);




        //done calculation to work out
        int workingHours = Math.abs(exitHours - beginningHours);
        int workingMinutes = Math.abs(exitMin - beginningMin);
        System.out.println("Thanks, I will commence the calculation.");
        System.out.println("You have worked " + workingHours + " hours " + workingMinutes + " minutes");
```

After do-while loop, even after I type in 45 or 48, the code continues... I would appreciate any feedback.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but of course, the do-while loop will continue because your input is greater than 25. Do-while will loop when the condition is true. So maybe change the condition?

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. The purpose of this code is to make sure that if the value of beginninghour exceeds 24, then the loop would not fllow through. How can I make it better

Comment: So i tried to change the condition to while (beginningHours <23), yet if I type 35 or 45 , the loop still continues...

Answer (score 0):

Put your loop around only the part that you want to be repeated in case of an incorrect number. For example:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int beginningHours;
    do {
        System.out.println("please enter your entry hours. [0-23]");
        beginningHours = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (beginningHours < 0 || beginningHours > 23);

    int beginningMin;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter your entry minutes. [0-59]");
        beginningMin = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (beginningMin < 0 || beginningMin > 59);
```

Example session:

```
please enter your entry hours. [0-23]
26
please enter your entry hours. [0-23]
19
Please enter your entry minutes. [0-59]
-14
Please enter your entry minutes. [0-59]
599
Please enter your entry minutes. [0-59]
45
```

Do similarly for the exit time.

As an aside I consider it needless and potentially confusing to assign unused and meaningless initial values to your variables in your declarations. It’s a matter of taste, and some will prefer that you do it. In Java there is no risk of forgetting to assign a value to a local variable before you use it. The IDE or compiler will issue an error message if you forget completely.